# How to solve sorbet strong type-checker error "this code is untyped" in URI.encode_www_form({"q": "ruby"})

Tags: ruby, sorbet

How to solve sorbet strong type-checker error "this code is untyped" in the code below?

```rb
query = {"q": "ruby"}
URI.encode_www_form(query)
```

Error message

```rb
This code is untyped https://srb.help/7018
    83 |    URI.encode_www_form(query)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in https://sorbet.org/docs/static it's currently very hard to get files to pass under `strict` level.
In the case of this snippet, it's because return type of `encode_www_form` isn't specified, thus it returns `T.untyped`.
You'll need to specify return type of this function to make it pass in `strict`